# How do I re-render Meteor template after Save File dialog is closed?

Tags: meteor

Here's a sample html of my template to download a file:

```
<template name="download-file">
   <a href="{{this.url download=true}}"
</template>
```

After clicking on the "a" tag,  the Save File dialog opens up as expected. However, the "download-file" template is now displayed blank, and it does not get re-rendered when the Save File dialog is closed.

Is there a way to get Meteor to automatically re-render a template after the Save File dialog is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with Meteor. I tried creating a new project, and put this in the html file:

```
<head>
  <title>meteor-download-example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> download_file}}
</body>

<template name="download_file">
  <a href="meteor-download-example.css" download>Download</a>
</template>
```

In my browser (Chromium 14), clicking the link did not clear the template. However, I did notice that the URL changed to the file path. If that's happening for you as well, then perhaps the issue is that the URL isn't routed to your template.

To fix this, try preventing the browser URL update. Adding target="_blank" worked for me:

```
<template name="download_file">
  <a href="meteor-download-example.css" download target="_parent">Download</a>
</template>
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked by opening a new tab, but I didn't like the side effect of having to close the tab, and navigate back to my app. Instead, I used target='_parent', and the Save File dialog opens without affecting the template display.

Comment: For me (on Chromium 14), the browser automatically closed the tab. But I updated the answer to use _parent as you suggested, so hopefully that will work better on a variety of browsers.